# IP address location for zone Europe

Tags: google-compute-engine

why IP addresses from zone europe-west1-b are detected as being located in US instead of Europe by maxmind ?
Thanks

Comment: Because geolocation isn't perfect.

Answer (score 3):

At this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/ip$20address$20in$20europe/gce-discussion/RjzyHRBRujg/Fd21YlmOpzEJ), Gary Ling from Google posted:

"We are aware of this issue that (almost) all Google IP addresses are SWIP'ed to be Mountain View, CA. And at Google, it's not uncommon to remap a block of IPs from one location to another, especially given the elasticity of IP addresses for the Cloud. Too bad that many of external Geo IP services solely depend on SWIP database"

So your instance will be running in the geographical zone you select.

You can also read this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/ip$20address$20in$20europe/gce-discussion/otD1c6E-wWI/3c0HxTf71HcJ) group for more information on this topic